# Laravel Resubmit Form Validation Still Show Old Input Value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After validation when I resubmit form, data is saved to database but the old form data is not cleared

I use this for validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'branch' => 'required|not_in:---Select Branch---',
    'dep' => 'required|not_in:--- Select Department ---',
    'txt_username' => 'required|min:5|max:20',            
]);
```

After inserting to database I redirect to route:

```
return redirect()->route('newrec');
```

When validation I use this code to remember old data that I just put:

```
value="{{ old('txt_username')}}"
```

If I complete the form, I am redirected to route `newrec` by clearing all old data and if I don't complete the form and validation failed it will show old text I just put. If I complete and resubmit the form after validation failed I am redirect to `newrec` route but it's still showing old value that I just put, while data is saved to database. How can I clear it after resubmitting the form.

Comment: Quiet confusing interpretation of problem. Can you clarify last paragraph ?

Comment: @SagarGautam When i resubmit form after validation and then it will redirect to route newrec but with the old data that i just input. How can i clear it after resubmit form??

Comment: Suppose you have filled few fields and leaving other empty, then validation fails and your filled values are appeared on the form. Now you complete the form and then submit after that you redirect to newrec which still shows old data. Is this the problem as I understand ?

Comment: @SagarGautam: Yes that's my problem

Comment: have you tried `return redirect()->to('newrec');` ? 

since `newrec` must be a named route to use as `redirect()->to('newrec')`.

Comment: @SagarGautam: It's still get the old value i just input when redirect to this route newrec

Comment: Then it's an strange problem,

Comment: @SagarGautam : Yes so strange still can't find solution

Comment: Some time it's a cache problem, either application or browser cache. YOu can try by clearing these caches

Comment: @SagarGautam : Where is application cache?? and how can i clear it??

Comment: You can run artisan commands to clear cache, You can use `php artisan cache:clear` to clear app cache,  `php artisan route:clear` to remove route cache and `php artisan view:clear` to remove view cache in the application.

Comment: @SagarGautam: ok thank you very much for your help

Comment: please try clearing caches, I've some strange problem like this before because of caches :D

Comment: @SagarGautam : Still happen again after i clear all caches

Comment: Then it's difficult to find what's wrong there :D

Comment: Okay no problem here :D

Comment: have u solved this?

Answer (score -1):

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'role' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt("123456"),
        'role' => $request->role
    ]);

    return back()->with('success', 'Successfully saved');
```

That's how I solved the problem

Comment: No help for the question.